# Ideas for sharing elements between vectors

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I am working on a toy language, following is what I am trying to do,

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5]
```

this defines a vector then,

```
y = rest(x)
```

now y contains all elements of x except first. On the native side x is a vector and when user calls rest on it will make a full copy of it self except the first element. Here is the problem I am only 2 kb of ram, making a full copy is expensive. Using a linked list would solve this particular problem but linked list it self if a memory hog in this context. So is there a structure that is memory efficient for these kinds of operations (first rest are the most frequent ops) that shares elements?

this is a functional language so once x is defined it won't change, also there is no boost or std c++ libs available, I am going to implement everything.

Comment: A pointer to the first element does the job

Comment: What's wrong with the linked-list approach?

Comment: @abeln: A linked-list has the overhead of one pointer per element.

Comment: This is exactly how LISP-like languages are implemented, often in very small memory spaces. I suggest you read up on them. I don't see it has anything much to do with C or C++.

Comment: @David: Why don't you make that an answer, so we can upvote it?

Comment: No memory, for each element I have to store an extra pointer to the next which is too much when all you have is 2 kb for the whole thing. vector is stored in as an array to roughly occupies half the space compared to a linked list (both a pointer and an int is 2 bytes for this micro)

Comment: @unapersson c is the intermediate language thats why

Comment: @Hamza It is for some LISPs as well - all this has been done before. And if C is the intermediate (I assume you mean implementation, but you could mean compilation target) language, why tag this as C++?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Understood. I guess the problem with the "pointer" approach is that other operations, such as concatenating "lists", become expensive.

Comment: People will understand the meaning better if you call the operations `head` and `tail`. On the actual question, you should really define your semantics: what does `tail/rest` mean? Is the original list untouched, does it need to remain so? Functional languages work that way (they generate copies instead of mutating) but that is expensive in memory... With that memory footprint you might need to create your own types, and I am not sure you want to do that in C++, the runtime might take more than the 2kb of memory.

Comment: @abeln: Indeed.  I guess it's a trade-off between space efficiency and computational efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` in some memory, and make `x` point to that piece of memory, i.e.

```
template <typename T>
struct slice { T* begin; T* end; };

....

int backing_store[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// ^-- the expression [1 2 3 4 5] create this

....

slice<int> x (backing_store, backing_store + 5);
// ^-- the assignment x = [1 2 3 4 5] does this
```

and then you could implement `rest` as

```
template <typename T>
slice<T> rest(slice<T> p) {
   return slice<T>(p.begin + 1, p.end); 
}
```

You could use some ref-counting scheme or a GC (may be too large for your memory) to make sure `backing_store` is freed when no 'slice' is using it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are so memory constrained, the best solution I can envisage is to use a pointer to the first element. It's hard to imagine that there could be a more space-efficient solution.

Comment: +1: If vectors are immutable, then this sounds like a good answer.